# Creating a struct to create a list and use in scheduling algorithms

Tags: c, algorithm, struct

Below is the code I have in an attempt to create and implement a struct function that will read a "data.txt" file with an particular number of integers and then based on the value (whether it is 0 or 1) at position 1 of the *argv[], will either run those values through the FCFS scheduling algorithm of the Round Robin Scheduling algorithm. I am not sure if I have used struct properly AND even if I have, how to pass those values in to the algorithm that has been chosen. I am also supposed to print out the processes as they are executed, which is simple enough for FCFS but not as easy in Round Robin. I'm stuck and have no idea how to proceed.

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 struct task{
    int burst;
    int pid;
    struct task *next;
    int finish;
 };


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
    FILE *input = fopen("data.txt","r");
    int burst_time;
    while(fscanf(input,"%d",&burst_time)!=EOF){
            struct task *tmp;
            tmp = malloc(sizeof(struct task));
            tmp->burst = burst_time;
            head = tmp;
            tmp->next = tmp;
            tail->next = tmp;
            tmp->next = head;
            tail=tmp;

    }
    if(argv[1] == 0)
    {

    }

    if(argv[1] == 1)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Realistically you should have a different way of sorting out your processes if you intend on using round robin.

Think about having a separate function in main called "Service Tasks", which is activated whilst argv[1] == ROUND_ROBIN.

Then run this inside a while loop. You then have to build all of your code around the idea of never pausing and waiting at specific sections. This usually means that you create a large series of separate switch statements, where the states are changed if conditions are met.

It is done this way to allow fast cycle times through your code so that the essential round robin part can be completed in the background.

I don't know if you have any experience with Embedded C but Microchip has an excellent example of this in their Microchip Harmony program, which is free and easy to setup a simple example of how various tasks can be performed and states are structured for an interface that does not hold up the task at hand.